# How to append a new object to a json file in cypress

Tags: json, cypress

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650653/how-to-append-a-new-key-value-pair-in-json-in-cypress) was for appending a new key,value pair but I want to append a new object. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes in your case the value is an object instead of a primitive but the result is the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sub out the string value that they provide for `newKey` with the object you want the value to be. Modifying the given answer from that question:

```js
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/example.json').then((data) => {
  data.newKey = { 'objKey': 'objValue' }
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/example.json', JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

```js
{
   "Name":"X",
   "Age":"Y",
   "newKey": { "objKey": "objValue" }
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ thanks guys!